# Compare Dates With Null Values JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date

**Desired Output:** I have a date variable being passed that needs to be compared to today's date and return weather it is before or after today. I would then like to return "Yes" or "No" to indicate weather it is active or not.

```
<script>
    function calculate(currentlyEffective) {

        var now_utc = new Date(now.getUTCFullYear(), now.getUTCMonth(), now.getUTCDate(), now.getUTCHours(), now.getUTCMinutes(), now.getUTCSeconds());
        var expDate = currentlyEffective.Expiration_Date;
        expDate = new Date(expDate).toUTCString();
        var result = "";

        if (expDate < now_utc) {
            result = "No"
        }
        else {
            result = "Yes"
        }
        return result;
    }

</script>
```

**Problem:**

1. Some of the dates being passed do not have a value because they are not expired yet. This returns `Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT`The desired output would be `"Yes"` here even though the date would be less than today because it has no expiration date making it `"Yes"` still active.
2. Something isn't happening correctly in the calculation. My return value is always `"Yes"`

**Questions:**

1. Am I comparing these dates correctly with my if else function?
2. Even in an instance where I have a date in `expDate` that is before today I still get "Yes" as my return value. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youre comparing a string and a Date Object with < ? What do you expect? You dont need the time string, you need the time as a number:

```
var now=new Date().getTime();//current time as number (ms since...)
var old=new Date(timestring).getTime();//time as number with a timestring ("12:20 ...")
if(now<old){
 alert("future date!");
}
```

Full code:

```
    function calculate(currentlyEffective) {

    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var expDate = currentlyEffective.Expiration_Date;
    expDate = new Date(expDate).getTime();

    return expDate<now?"Yes":"No";
}
```

As RobG pointed out, this can be shortified, as using < on two objects, trys to convert them to number, wich does in fact call getTime:

```
var calculate=(currentlyEffective)=>new Date(currentlyEffective.Expiration_Date)<new Date()?"Yes":"No";
```

Comment: This could be reduced to `new Date(currentlyEffective.Expiration_Date) < new Date()? 'Yes' : 'No'` provided that *currentlyEffective.Expiration_Date* is parsed correctly by the built–in parser, which is problematic.

Comment: Regarding: *"You're comparing two strings with < "*. *now_utc* is a Date object, *expDate* is a string.

Comment: @RobG: wasnt that shure if toString() is called on the obj. Thanks for the clarification and the small note about shortifying. Added it to my answer...